# First product added to new cart returned with no JSON "price"

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api, json, react

This is my first time currently working with Magento. I am developing a custom web shop solution for a machine shop with React.js.

My issue is the following:

*After having completed a purchase and received a new quoteID as a logged in customer, where everything functions as expected, the first item added to the new cart is returned from our Magento backend WITHOUT a "price" attribute in the received JSON...*

I have already checket out the different pricing settings in the backend, and I cannot seem to find the solution. The only weird setting is the "Special Prime Promotion" date changing randomly.

I hope one of you have encountered this issue before.

Kind regards,

Nikolaj Hem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you use the data when check the json. But if  you need price  of item, you can use the  code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
 
// get quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
 
// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
 
// get quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
 
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo ""<br />"";            
}
```